# NumberFormatException: itrStat.index does not evaluate

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm looping through an array that I want have as a form. Currently, my HTML looks as follows but in the `*{...}` argument, I get the following error:

```
Error:
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "${itrStat.index}"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
```

HTML:

```
<form th:action="@{/admin/user/toggleranks}" th:object="${rankList}"
          method="post">
        <th:block th:each="rank,itrStat : ${rankList.getList()}" th:class="${itrStat.even}? 'even_css_class':'odd_css_class'">
            <span th:text="${rank.getRank().getAuthority()}+': '+${rank.isOwnsRank()}"></span>
            <input type="checkbox" th:field="*{list[${itrStat.index}].ownsRank}"/>
            <br>
        </th:block>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Save changes"/>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can force Thymeleaf to evaluate `itrStat.index` by using double underscores:

`th:field="*{list[__${itrStat.index}__]. ownsRank}"`